# Display List view or Grid view in same layout on button click

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-gridview

On my screen I have to display my data in form of Listview or Gridview on click of the button for users "button for Listview" and "button for Gridview",

I Have created two different layout files for listview and Gridview i want them to be showed as per user needs when he clicks on listview button i want it to be showed the data in lists and when user clicks Gridview button i want to show the user the data in Grid view.

Would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android: how to change layout on button click?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121797/android-how-to-change-layout-on-button-click)

Comment: i am strongly recommending to use recyclerview for this.

Comment: Actually, the data items in List view and grid view are different , or I can say it as the 2 layouts are ---1st Layout is Listviews- containing two textviews for store's name and address and 2nd Layout view(which i call it as a Gridview) - it has 3 data items store's name , address and stores' image  :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways through which you can achieve this:

1. Have both the ListView and GridView stacked in a FrameLayout, and when you want to switch between these views, set the visibility GONE to one view and VISIBLE to another, then viceversa.
2. Put both the ListView and GridView in a [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) Or, use a [ViewSwitcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html).
3. And finally, use just a GridView, but when you want to transition to a list view, set programmatically the number of columns to 1.

Comment: Actually, the data items in List view and grid view are different , or I can say it as the 2 layouts are ---1st Layout is Listviews- containing two textviews for store's name and address and 2nd Layout view(which i call it as a Gridview) - it has 3 data items store's name , address and stores' image  :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use RecyclerView instead of ListView

recyclerview have layoutManager that you can set them LinearLayout(same as simple listView ) Or GridView

so you can create both linear and grid layout manager and when user press Button changeLayoutManager

```
 RecyclerView  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.mainRecycleView_RCL);
 LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
 StaggeredGridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL); // 2 is number of items per row
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager); // deafult
```

And when you Whant to change :

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
OR
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
```

Comment: Actually, the data items in List view and grid view are different , or I can say it as the 2 layouts are ---1st Layout is Listviews- containing two textviews for store's name and address and 2nd Layout view(which i call it as a Gridview) - it has 3 data items store's name , address and stores' image  :)

Comment: So long ago but I am sure you needed tabs!

Answer (score 0):

Use a RecyclerView and just change the LayoutManager:

- **LinearLayoutManager** for list view https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html
- **GridLayoutManager** for grid view
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html

Comment: Actually, the data items in List view and grid view are different , or I can say it as the 2 layouts are ---1st Layout is Listviews- containing two textviews for store's name and address and 2nd Layout view(which i call it as a Gridview) - it has 3 data items store's name , address and stores' image  :)